# How to fix "Failed to obtain lock" error in Endeca?

Tags: bash, endeca

Endeca does not seems to be popular here, anyway

**The problem:**

Accidentally kill a running base line update process, and the lock is left-over somewhere.

I wish to find out where the left-over lock is, and to manually remove that.

Not so useful message returned by the base line update script:

```
INFO: Checking definition from AppConfig.xml against existing EAC provisioning.
INFO: Definition has not changed.
INFO: Starting baseline update script.
WARNING: Failed to obtain lock.

...ended
```

Alternatively, anyone can provide some links on endeca documentation (without login credential) will be helpful too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**RTFM**

> If the running Deployment Template script breaks halfway through its execution due to an unhandled exception, or is manually interrupted by a user pressing Ctrl-C while it is running, the lock remains set within the EAC.

On Windows: `.\runcommand.bat LockManager releaseLock update_lock`

On UNIX: `./runcommand.sh LockManager releaseLock update_lock`

Both the above will work if the default lock name is unchanged (update_lock)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. However, for future reference, which Endeca manual/document is this tip from?  (A simple Google search for the text you quoted didn't turn it up.)

Comment: the docs seems to be located in eden,the premium member area only

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using their deployment template, I keep a .bat file in the "control" dir as it comes in handy sometimes.

e.g. on a windows machine create a .bat file w/ this as its contents:

```
rem runcommand.bat/sh LockManager releaseLock update_lock

call %~dp0..\config\script\set_environment.bat
call %~dp0runcommand.bat LockManager releaseLock update_lock
```

As far as their documentation goes... you have to register on their support site.  I haven't seen it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For an ATG (or "Oracle Web Commerce") application integrated with Endeca, this situation can happen when a running baseline index operation is canceled via the Cancel button in the GUI for the ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin component in Dyn Admin.  Subsequent baseline updates will fail until manual action is taken on the Endeca side to release the lock.

(I have seen this with ATG 10.1.2 integrated with Endeca 3.1.1.)

Per a conversation I had with Oracle Support, this is considered a bug -- "BUG 17298595 - Cancelling the baseline from SimpleIndexingAdmin does not release update lock" -- and an ATG hotfix is available.

Answer (score 0):

Run `release_update_locks.sh` (or `.bat` in case of windows) script from the `control` folder of the app.